# AWS multi-region web app

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have website (EC2, RDS, VPC, S3) located in EU (Ireland) and I want to make it more accessible for users from America and Asia.

1. Should I create new instances (EC2, RDS, VPC, S3) in new regions? Or there is another way how to do that?
2. If I will have more EC2 instances, how should I deploy updates for every instance?
3. What is the best way to make AWS website light and accessible with small latency from every corner of the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I create new instances (EC2, RDS, VPC, S3) in new regions?

If you take budget considerations out of the picture then creating instances in each AZ around the world and spreading geographic traffic to them would be a great consideration.

> Or there is another way how to do that?

Perhaps the easiest way both from implementation and maintainability as well as budget considerations would be to implement a geographic edge cache like Akamai, CloudFlare, etc.

Akamai is horrendously expensive, but CloudFlare [has some free and very cheap plans](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/).

Using an edge cache means that static cached content can be served to your clients from the nearest global edge points to them, without requiring your AWS infrastructure to be optimised for regions.

For example - if you request your home page from Ireland, it may be served from an Irish edge cache location, whereas if I request it from New Zealand, it may be served from an Australasian edge cache location - this doesn't add any complexity to your AWS set up.

In the scenario where a cached version of your page doesn't exist in CloudFlare (for example), it will hit your AWS origin server for the result. This will result in geographic performance variation, but you trade that off against the cost of implementing EC2 instances in each region and the reduced number of hits that actually reach your infrastructure with the cache in place.

> If I will have more EC2 instances, how should I deploy updates for every instance?

This largely depends on the complexity of your web application.

For more simple applications you can use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) to easily deploy updates to all of your EC2 instances and manage your auto-scaling.

For more complex arrangements you might choose to use a combination of [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/), [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) and [CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) to achieve the same thing.

Thirdly, there's always the option that you could construct your own deployment tool using a combination of custom scripts and AWS API calls. Or use [a tool that has already been created for this purpose](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/the-5-best-tools-for-aws-deployment/).

> What is the best way to make AWS website light and accessible with small latency from every corner of the world?

This is a pretty broad and complicated question.

My suggestions would be to make use of lazy loading wherever possible, cache everything wherever you can, tweak your web server configuration within an inch of its life (and use things like [Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29) if you're on nginx), optimise all your media assets as much as possible, etc.

For media assets you could use a CDN (like S3 or CloudFront) to serve requests instead of storing them on EC2 instances.

By far the most important thing you could do for this though would be to put in an edge cache (discussed earlier). If you do this, your AWS performance is much less of a concern.

Comment: "Certain AWS services are global - the VPC settings are not going to be region specific, and S3 is a global service as well."  1) VPC settings are regional. 2) S3 may be a global service, but the buckets are regional. Depending on the application and how the buckets are used, having region-specific buckets may improve performance.

Comment: Adding CloudFront to cache static resources can help quite a bit.

Comment: @MattHouser thanks, good point. [This article is useful](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/) to find out about cross region replication for S3

Comment: Ok, but what about EC2? Speed of scripts loading is very important.

Comment: If your web app involves much dynamic content that cannot be cached, then adding EC2 instances is your next best bet. But then you'll have to worry about latency to your RDS instance(s) if you don't replicate them.

Comment: @SlavaZavodny - geographic EC2 placement is mentioned in this answer a few times. Chances are that you'll get better value for money from edge and content caching, but you could spread EC2 instances into your most often used AZs as well if you have the budget.

Comment: I believe CloudFront can help with this?  It provides edge caching, though I don't know specifics about its integration with EC2 dynamic content.

Comment: @Brooks I believe you're correct. It can act as an edge cache like the others. With the recent addition of AWS WAF as well it should be considered!

Comment: @RobbieAverill nice answer, thanks. I am wondering though how to deal with dynamic content and DB (and EC2) replication if the DB can only do read-replicas. Is there a way to route writes to the master DB and use the replica for reads only? I'm especially interested in Postgres with RDS